# Android. RecyclerView GridLayoutManager как уместить на одном экране все ячейки таблицы?

Tags: java, android, list, recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

Данные из адаптара выводятся на экран с помошью GridLayoutManager.

**MainActivity.java**

```
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 7));
```

**main.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

В item.xml шаблон для элемента

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="10dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text_default_material_light"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Если написать таким образом, то ячейка естественно растянется по размеру текста, останется пустота внизу экрана.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если написать `android:layout_width="match_parent"`, одна ячейка растянется на весь экран.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли так сделать, чтобы все ячейки уместились на одном экране и заполнили собой все пространства экрана?

Comment: простого способа нет. Вам нужно заранее рассчитать высоту ячейки, и в onCreateViewHolder вашему View задавать рассчитанную высоту

Comment: Экраны разные у всех. Если заранее поставить определенный размер, то на некоторых экранах будет пустота внизу, а на другим будет прокручиваться вниз

Comment: нет, рассчитывать, например, при старте приложения

Comment: По GridLayoutManager, очень мало информации нашел. Я не понимаю как это можно сделать. Я могу программно поменять размер ячейки GridLayoutManager? Не в файле item.xml, или Вы имеете ввиду поменять размеры именно CardView  в адаптаре например?

Comment: да, прямо в адаптере

Answer (score 4):

Нашел ответ

```
    @Override
public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
    int height = parent.getMeasuredHeight() / 7;
    itemView.setMinimumHeight(height);

    return new Holder(itemView);
}
```

И убрать в android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView паддинг